# How to start shell (fish) with variable preset

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, fish

I want to use fish with [Cool Retro Terminal](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/make-cool-retro-terminal-ubuntu) but the prompt I use normally has unicode characters, which the fonts in retro terminal don't support. I have my `fish_prompt` function check if `$simple_prompt` is 1 or not and I know that it works, but I need a way to set the variable, only for that terminal instance, with the startup command option in retro terminal.

The closest I have so far is `fish -c "set -gx simple_prompt 1; fish"`, but that exports the variable to all the shell instances on the system and makes the prompts simple for all of those too. `fish -c "set -g simple_prompt 1; fish"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that `set -g simple_prompt 1` isn't visible to the next fish instance you launch. Global variables are only visible to the current shell instance. If the terminal you are using sets some environment vars that would allow you to determine that fish is running within that specific terminal I would go use that info. For example, iTerm2 on macOS exports `ITERM_PROFILE` and four other env vars unique to it. If Cool Retro Terminal doesn't do that perhaps there is some other way detect that terminal type. It may be as simple as checking the `TERM` variable.

If the aforementioned solutions aren't an option then the only solution is an environment variable like in your first solution. Because you say it exports that variable to all fish instances I suspect you did not accurately describe what you are doing. Because if you set that command as the command that Cool Retro Terminal should use to launch your shell it would only affect fish instances running in that terminal. Which is what you want.